# Pycharm not detecting the installed Latex distribution

Tags: pycharm, latex

Previously, I had installed texlive using `sudo apt install texlive-full`. Pycharm (with [Texify-Idea](https://github.com/Hannah-Sten/TeXiFy-IDEA) plugin) was able to detect the installed Latex distribution. However, `apt` installs only 2019 texlive version. I wanted to use the [latest version of changes package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/620248/178369) for which I had to use latest texlive. So, I uninstalled the existing texlive following [this blog](https://puttym.github.io/update-texlive) and installed the latest version of texlive following the instructions in [this webpage](https://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html). I've updated my `PATH` variable as suggested and hence the command `tex --version` works perfectly fine in the terminal. However, Pycharm is now unable to detect the Latex distribution. I tried restarting PyCharm and the system, but it didn't help. Please see the image below. How can I get PyCharm to detect the installed Latex distribution?

[image: Edit Configurations Dialog in PyCharm]